# Angular2 transmit class to component

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

What is the correct way to add classes to component in html selector? I have multiple app-tile elements and i wantto add to each of it another class. I tried simply add class 'tile-one' to app-tile selector but tile.component.scss dosent see it. How make it work?

tile.component.html:

```
<app-tile
    class="tile-one"
    [title]="'title one'"
></app-tile>
<app-tile
    class="tile-two"
    [title]="'Title two'"
></app-tile>
```

Comment: 1) is `tile.component.scss` at the same level with the `tile.component.ts` ? 2) are `tile-one` and `tile-two` classes placed inside `tile.component.scss`? 3) is `tile.component.scss` referenced in `tile.component.ts` in `stylesUrls` section ? **Paste a code snippet from `tile-component.ts` in question**.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[ngClass]` directive.

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of collection">
     <label>Name: {{item.name}}</label>
     <button class="btn"
          [ngClass]="{'item-updated' : item.isDirty}"
          [attr.title]="item.isDirty ? 'Item was updated' : null">
      Save
     </button>
 </div>
```

Comment: I shouldnt use ngFor cause each of tile has another [title] and [content]. Or i dont know is better way for this!

Comment: @krolkarpii It was just a demo. You can go without `*ngFor` for your scenario. The important snippet is `[ngClass]` or, another possibility is `[class.yourClass]="conditional"`. If you can update the question with more code, a better answer can formulate for your trouble.